# Why code fragment doesn't work correctly if I use multithreading?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, collections

I try to use multitreading with tutorial [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-executorservice-examples/)
So, adapted code fragment is

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        Future<Boolean> res = executorService.submit(() -> {
            while (true) {
                UserCsv csv = queue.poll();
                if (csv == null) break;
                System.out.println(csv);
            }
            return true;
        });
        executorService.shutdown();
```

queue contains 65k records. 
If I executed this task without threads - everything is okey and queue is empty after execution code, but, when I tried to use threads - after execution code, I have 60k records in queue..
What's wrong in code?

Comment: You should wait for the future to be completed before shutting down the executor service. (Note the "block until future returned a result" in the tutorial you've linked).

Comment: @Roberto can you put other code too? which is giving you problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [void shutdown()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--)

> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.

So either wait on future or use `awaitTermination`

```
executorService.shutdown();
try {
  //Add your timeout limit if you want
  executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  ...
}
```